# FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, winapi

My goal is to acquire file names from a cluster. For this purpose I use the function `FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER`. When using it I'm getting error 87 which stands for **`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`** according to MSDN. Drive handle is correct as I use it in other functions which work properly.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Disk{
public:
    Disk();
    HANDLE hDisk;
    WCHAR *individualName;
    WCHAR *Letter;
};

bool searchFileByItCluster(Disk drive){
    LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_INPUT inpStruct;
    LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY str;
    LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT str1;
    PNTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER info;
    PLARGE_INTEGER INT = (PLARGE_INTEGER)malloc(sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
    DWORD cbWritten;
    int size = (sizeof(DWORD) * 2 + sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
    inpStruct.NumberOfClusters = 1;
    inpStruct.Cluster[0].QuadPart = 26585528;

    bool ret = DeviceIoControl(drive.hDisk, FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER, &inpStruct, (sizeof(DWORD) * 2 + sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER)), &str1, sizeof(LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT), &cbWritten, NULL);
    if (!ret){
        cout << GetLastError()<<endl<<sizeof(LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_INPUT);
        for (int i = 0; i < inpStruct.NumberOfClusters; i++){
            printf("%lli\n", inpStruct.Cluster[i]);
        }


        int i = 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not related but `PLARGE_INTEGER INT = (PLARGE_INTEGER)malloc(sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));` is about as point less as `int *pint = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))`.

Comment: The error code is pretty self explanatory. Pretty much every single parameter you pass to `DeviceIoControl` is worng, for one reason or another. For one, the size of a structure is not necessarily the same as the sum of the sizes of its members.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, and not especially helpful.  But it's one of the few pages google finds for FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER.  So now that I've figured out how to use it, I'm passing on what I have learned.

---

A caveat: As the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff951637(v=vs.85).aspx) point out:

> FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER is a very resource-intensive operation, and typically uses a very large amount of disk bandwidth, memory, and time.

Still, if you need it, you need it (I sure just did).  For that reason, here's some code that worked for me, along with things I've learned on the way.

```
// Pick a plausible estimate.  Note: valid output sizes can be up to ~64k!
DWORD bufsize = 
    MAX_PATH + 
    sizeof(LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT) + 
    sizeof(LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY);

LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_INPUT sfci;
LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT *sfco = 
    (LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT *)malloc(bufsize);

sfci.NumberOfClusters = 1;      // Only looking up one cluster
sfci.Flags = 0;                 // No flags are currently defined
sfci.Cluster[0].QuadPart = 123; // Cluster number being sought

// While some DeviceIoControl calls get away with 0 or FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
// FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER needs at least FILE_READ_DATA.  Also,
// while the docs claim you can use "a file on a NTFS volume," I believe a 
// volume handle is required, which requires running with admin rights.
HANDLE h1 = CreateFile(
    L"\\\\.\\j:", 
    FILE_READ_DATA, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, // Required, but the SE_BACKUP_NAME priv is not
    NULL);

if (h1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    ;  // Do something

DWORD ret;
BOOL B = DeviceIoControl(
    h1, 
    FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER, 
    &sfci, 
    sizeof(sfci), 
    sfco, 
    bufsize, 
    &ret, 
    NULL);

if (!B && GetLastError() == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
    ; // bufsize too small. Resize to sfco->BufferSizeRequired and retry

if (!B)
    ; // Some other error

// Here's the data.
LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY *sfce = 
    (LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY *)((BYTE *)sfco + sfco->Offset);
```

There.  Now the next time someone googles for FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER, at least they'll turn up a working sample.